Issue with Writing to GVFS Path in C#
I’m encountering an issue with writing to a file located on a GVFS-mounted network share. The code below works fine for reading the file, but throws an IOException when attempting to write to it.
public void Testing()
{
    string gvfsFilePath = @"/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=example.net,share=dev_builds/sw/TA/NFR/New folder/Target";

    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo performanceDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(gvfsFilePath + "//Performance");

        FileInfo[] performanceFiles = performanceDirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.csv");

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------Performance files-------------------------");

        foreach (FileInfo file in performanceFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
            {
                string firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"First line of {file.Name}: {firstLine}");
            }
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file.FullName, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Testing Stream write");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.ToString()}");
    }
}

Error:-
Error: System.IO.IOException: Operation not supported : '/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=example.net,share=dev_builds/sw/TA/NFR/New folder/Target/Performance/100_Standard.csv'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirError)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode, Func`4 createOpenException)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, UnixFileMode openPermissions, Int64& fileLength, UnixFileMode& filePermissions, Func`4 createOpenException)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)

Environment: Running on a Linux system with the network share mounted via GVFS.
Issue: Reading from the file works fine, but writing to the file throws an IOException.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified that the file is accessible and readable.
Checked permissions to ensure the user has write access to the file.
Question:
How can I resolve this issue and successfully write to the file on the GVFS-mounted network share? Are there any alternative approaches or libraries that can handle this scenario better?

See following : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/96503
